# JIB with GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, jib

### Introduction

I am currently create a GitHub Actions with that build a container automatically.

And I'm wondering if it's possible to create a GitHub action that automatically builds the container without adding *JIB* in the project's `pom.xml` ?

If we can t do this, can you show me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, whit this code on your GitHub workflows:

```yaml
name: JIB container publish

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: JIB container build and publish
        uses: MathieuSoysal/jib-container-publish.yml@v2.0.7
        with:
          PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

For more details you can go in: https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/jib-container-publish.yml

Answer (score 4):

In Maven, you can run a goal of a plugin without adding the plugin to `pom.xml`. For example,

```sh
mvn compile com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.2.0:build -Djib.to.image=foo
```

For Gradle, one can use a trick to use initscript:

```sh
      # Adds Gradle init script that applies the Jib Gradle plugin.
      echo "initscript {
              repositories { maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2' } }
              dependencies { classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.google.cloud.tools:jib-gradle-plugin:3.2.0' }
            }
            rootProject {
              afterEvaluate {
                if (!project.plugins.hasPlugin('com.google.cloud.tools.jib')) {
                  project.apply plugin: com.google.cloud.tools.jib.gradle.JibPlugin
                }
              }
            }" > "$HOME"/init-script.gradle
      # Runs the Gradle Jib build.
      gradle jib \
        --init-script="$HOME"/init-script.gradle \
        -Djib.to.image=foo
```

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/blob/5956edb120935dc1706db46c6d614638a10919e8/task/jib-gradle/0.3/jib-gradle.yaml#L53-L74).

---

Another option that may be applicable to you is [Jib CLI](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-cli), which has a feature to build a container from an existing JAR.

```sh
jib jar --target=my-registry.example.com/jar-app myapp.jar
```

There's also a Java library called [Jib Core](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-core) with which you can write a Java program to build a container. Jib Maven and Gradle plugins and Jib CLI are based on Jib Core.

Answer (score 0):

We are obliged to configure the `pom.xml`, we cannot do otherwise.

You can go here: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib
to get more information about JIB.